# Arrow bending in TikZ is not aligned

Tags: arrows, tikz-arrows

I am using TikZ to draw a diagram. The bended arrows are not really correct mapped between the boxes.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning} 
\tikzset{
    %Define standard arrow tip
    >=stealth',
    %Define style for boxes
    punkt/.style={
           rectangle,
           rounded corners,
           draw=black, very thick,
           text width=6.5em,
           minimum height=2em,
           text centered},
    plain/.style={
           rectangle,
           rounded corners,
           draw=white, very thick,
           text width=6.5em,
           minimum height=2em,
           text centered},
    % Define arrow style
    pil/.style={
           ->,
           thick,
           shorten <=2pt,
           shorten >=2pt,}
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
     \node[punkt] (a) {AAAAA};

     \node[punkt, inner sep=5pt, right=0.5 of a] (b) {BBBBBB BBBBB}
       edge[pil,<-] (a.east);

     \node[plain, inner sep=5pt, right=0.5 of b] (dummy) {};
     \node[punkt, inner sep=5pt, above=0.5 of dummy] (b1) {BBBBBB BBBBB1}
       edge[pil, <-, bend right=45] (b.north);
     \node[punkt, inner sep=5pt, below=0.5 of dummy] (b2) {BBBBBB BBBBB2}
       edge[pil, <-, bend left=45] (b.south);

     \node[plain, inner sep=5pt, right=0.5 of dummy] (dummy2) {};
     \node[punkt, inner sep=5pt, above=0.5 of dummy2] (c1) {CCCCCC CCCC1}
       edge[pil,<-] (b1.east);
     \node[punkt, inner sep=5pt, below=0.5 of dummy2] (c2) {CCCCCC CCCC2}
       edge[pil,<-] (b2.east);

     \node[punkt, inner sep=5pt, right=0.5 of dummy2] (d) {DDDDDD DDDD}
       edge[pil, <- , bend right=45] (c1.east)
       edge[pil, <- , bend left=45] (c2.east);

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This code generates following picture.

[image: Generated diagram picture]

Is there a way to make them *prettier*?

Comment: Replace `BBBBB1}` by `BBBBB1} (b1.west)`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One thing that does usually not get appreciated enough is that curved paths with arrows get distorted unless you are loading the `bending` library. This is true regardless of whether or not you actually add the `bend` key to the arrow heads, see p. 204 of pgfmanual v3.1.5

[image]

Yet I would also bend the arrow heads. And I would choose another way to bend the arrows: with the `in` and `out` syntax.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,bending,positioning} 
\tikzset{
    %Define standard arrow tip
    >={Stealth[bend]},
    %Define style for boxes
    punkt/.style={
           rectangle,
           rounded corners,
           draw=black, very thick,
           text width=6.5em,
           minimum height=2em,
           text centered},
    plain/.style={
           rectangle,
           rounded corners,
           draw=white, very thick,
           text width=6.5em,
           minimum height=2em,
           text centered},
    % Define arrow style
    pil/.style={
           ->,
           thick,
           shorten <=2pt,
           shorten >=2pt,}
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
     \node[punkt] (a) {AAAAA};

     \node[punkt, inner sep=5pt, right=0.5 of a] (b) {BBBBBB BBBBB}
       edge[pil,<-] (a.east);

     \node[plain, inner sep=5pt, right=0.5 of b.east] (dummy) {};
     \node[punkt, inner sep=5pt, above=0.5 of dummy] (b1) {BBBBBB BBBBB1}
       edge[pil, <-, out=180,in=60] (b.north);
     \node[punkt, inner sep=5pt, below=0.5 of dummy] (b2) {BBBBBB BBBBB2}
       edge[pil, <-, out=180,in=-60] (b.south);

     \node[plain, inner sep=5pt, right=0.5 of dummy] (dummy2) {};
     \node[punkt, inner sep=5pt, above=0.5 of dummy2] (c1) {CCCCCC CCCC1}
       edge[pil,<-] (b1.east);
     \node[punkt, inner sep=5pt, below=0.5 of dummy2] (c2) {CCCCCC CCCC2}
       edge[pil,<-] (b2.east);

     \node[punkt, inner sep=5pt, right=0.5 of dummy2] (d) {DDDDDD DDDD}
       edge[pil, <- , out=120,in=0] (c1.east)
       edge[pil, <- , out=-120,in=0] (c2.east);

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You may liked: instead `edge[bend ...]` use `\draw (x) |- (y)` or `\draw (x) -| (y)` or `\draw (x) -| (y)` where paths have rounded corners:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,
                positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance = 3mm and 5mm,
     punkt/.style = {draw, very thick, rounded corners,
                     text width=6.5em, minimum height=2em,
                     inner sep=5pt, align=center},
every path/.style = {draw, rounded corners=6mm, stealth-,
                     thick, shorten <=2pt, shorten >=2pt},
                        ]
\node[punkt] (a) {AAAAA};
\node[punkt, right=of a] (b) {BBBBBB BBBBB} edge (a);

\node[punkt, above right=of b] (c1) {BBBBBB BBBBB1};
       \draw    (c1) -| (b);
\node[punkt, below right=of b] (c2) {BBBBBB BBBBB2};
       \draw    (c2) -| (b);

\node[punkt, right=of c1] (d1) {CCCCCC CCCC1} edge  (c1);
\node[punkt, right=of c2] (d2) {CCCCCC CCCC2} edge  (c2);

\node[punkt, below right=of d1] (e) {CCCCCC CCCC1};
      \draw    (e) |- (d1);
      \draw    (e) |- (d2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]